# If $f(x) + f(2x)$ is continuous, is $f$ continuous or not?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

True or false:

> If $g(x)=f(x)+f(2x)$ with $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f$ is continuous.

My idea was to find a counterexemple since, first, I claim that this is false. I did not find an example. After that I suppose that $g(x)=0,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and, by induction, I get that $f$ is the zero function, if $f$ would be continuous. So, the answer should be true, but how can I prove this fact. Thank you.

Comment: You certainly could not use induction to prove this even if it were true. Ordinary (as opposed to the much less common transfinite) induction proves statements about natural numbers, not real numbers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used induction in the following way, Suppose that $g$ is the zero function. We get that $f(0)=0$ and then suppose that exists $x_0$ such that $f$ is not zero in this point. If $f$ would be continuous, then, by induction, we will obtain that $f$ is the zero function. Sorry for the error.

Comment: Even if $f(x)+f(2x)=0$ for all $x$, still $f$ could be discontinuous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not necessarily true. For a counterexample, start with any arbitrary discontinuous function $f_0 : (-2,-1] \cup [1,2) \to \mathbb{R}$. Then extend $f_0$ to $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x) + f(2x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Explicitly, we can define $f$ from $f_0$ as
$$
f(x) := \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } x = 0 \\
(-1)^k f_0\left(2^k x \right) &\text{if } x \ne 0, \text{ where } k \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ is the unique integer such that } 1 \le |2^k x| < 2.\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: This looks like an interesting, correct answer except that, unless I'm missing something, shouldn't the first $1$ in "$(-2,1] \cup [1,2)$" be $-1$ instead?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes indeed, thanks for the catch. Other corrections welcome